# How to figure out a number of left children in binary tree? (Python)

Tags: python, tree

I need to figure out the number of left children in a binary tree. There is a lot of ways to do it, but I would like to know why the code below does not work.

```
def leftChildren(self):
        leftChildren = []
        if self != None:
            leftChildren.append(self.v)
            if self.l:
                leftChildren = leftChildren + self.l.leftChildren()
            if self.r:
                self.r.leftChildren()
        return leftChildren
```

What is wrong and how to improve it?

Comment: Hi, I'm assuming this is a method for a binary tree class but you seem to have omitted it since this code has no way of running by itself. Please include the bare minimum of code we can at least run and visualize the issue, as the problem could be in other places as well as opposed to just this method.

Comment: Think it through at a higher level; you are looking at details and missing the big picture. You need to include all the children of self.left, but none of the children of self.right, on this node. You can't recurse with the "leftChildren" function itself because that doesn't count all children. (unless I misunderstand what you mean, in which case you should have provided a test case)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect :

self.r to return the right children

self.l to return the left children

All childrens are either nodes or trees

self.v return the value of the node/leaf

Therefore when looking at your code, I can see that

- the right side of the tree isn't computed as it should be.
- You should probably store the remaining values to only compute it once at the top (personal advice, don't need to)
- The value and the name of func is shared, which can be confusing
- I would advise to rename to the function and the variable to avoid confusion with the right/left and left = left to see
- I don't think you need to check for value. if your binary tree is correctly computed.
- You really need to provide the full code , or at least a minimal viable run.

Here is a quick draft:

```
def getremainingChildren(self):
    self.remainingChildren = []
    self.remainingChildren.append(self.v)
    if self.l:
        self.remainingChildren += self.l.getremainingChildren()
    if self.r:
        self.remainingChildren += self.r.getremainingChildren()
    return self.remainingChildren
```